# Relay.js - partial fetch when conditional statement changes

Tags: reactjs, relayjs

I cannot for the life of me figure this out. I have a parent component that gets a 'layout' field from the database. That value determines which child component should be rendered. The parent component also needs to get a GraphQL fragment from the child component. The parent component looks like this:

```js
 class Page extends React.Component{

  _setLayout(){
    const Layout = this.props.viewer.post.layout.meta_value || 'DefaultLayout';
    const isDefault = Layout === 'DefaultLayout';
    const isPostList = Layout === 'PostList';

    this.props.relay.setVariables({
      page: this.props.page,
      isDefault: isDefault,
      isPostList: isPostList
    })
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this._setLayout()
  }

  render(){
    const { viewer, className } = this.props;
    const { post } = viewer;
    const Layout = Layouts[post.layout.meta_value] || Layouts['Default'];

    return <Layout.Component viewer={viewer} page={this.props.page} condition={true} layout={Layout}/>
  }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(Page, {

  initialVariables: {
    page: null,
    isDefault: false,
    isPostList: false,
  },

  fragments: {
    viewer: (variables) => Relay.QL`
    fragment on User {
      ${DefaultLayout.getFragment('viewer', {page: variables.page, condition: variables.isDefault})},
      post(post_name: $page){
        id
        layout{
          id
          meta_value
        }
      }
    }
    `
  }
});
```

The child component (in this example DefaultLayout) looks like this:

```js
class DefaultLayout extends React.Component{

  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.relay.setVariables({
      page: this.props.page,
      condition: this.props.condition
    })
  }

  render(){
    const { viewer } = this.props;

    if (viewer.post){
      const { post_title, post_content, thumbnail } = viewer.post;

      let bg = {
        backgroundImage: "url('" + thumbnail + "')"
      }

      let heroClass = thumbnail ? "hero_thumbnail" : "hero";
      return(
        <PostContent content={post_content}/>
      )
    } else {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
  }
}

export default Relay.createContainer(DefaultLayout, {

  initialVariables:{
    page: null,
    condition: false
  },

  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        post(post_name:$page) @include(if: $condition){
          id
          post_title
          post_content
          thumbnail
        },
        settings{
          id
          uploads
          amazonS3
        }
      }
    `
  }

});
```

When the initial query is run, condition is false so it doesn't get any post data. Right before DefaultLayout mounts, condition variable is set to true so it SHOULD query post and get that data.

Here is the weird thing: I'm only getting the id and post_title of post. I'm not getting post_content or thumbnail. If I set condition to be true in initial variables, I get everything.

Am I not supposed to be able to change the condition?

Lastly - here is a screenshot of the query that's generating. Its querying Page, not Routes, which seems wrong.

[image]

Comment: What does the implementation of `Layout.Component` look like?

Comment: In this example case it just equates to DefaultLayout. If you replace Layout.Component with DefaultLayout the same error occurs.

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot of the query that is generated. Its querying Page not Routes which is wrong but I don't know why.

Comment: What version of Relay are you using?

Comment: The latest...0.7.3 I believe

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you've not passed what you've expected to pass to `LayoutComponent`. Your `page` variable can be found in Relay's variables store, not on props:

```js
return (
  <Layout.Component 
    condition={true} 
    layout={Layout}
    page={this.props.relay.variables.page} 
    viewer={viewer} 
  />
);
```

Also, you can omit the `componentWillMount` step in `DefaultLayout`. `page` and `condition` should flow into variables from props automatically.

See also:

- https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/src/container/RelayContainer.js#L790-L807
- https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/309
- https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/866

Comment: The issue isn't with passing page to DefaultLayout. I did make the recommended changes and the same issues prevail.

Comment: Can you `console.log('ComponentName: this.props.relay.variables.page', this.props.relay.variables.page);` in both of your `render()` methods for me?

Comment: "ComponentName: this.props.relay.variables.page about" for both. the page variables is simply just the name of the page in a WordPress database.